# Slick.js how to align images in center of carousel?

Tags: javascript, css, carousel, slick.js

By default, images align on the left. Using the setting `centerMode: true` the images are aligned a few pixels from the left, and the edge of the next image is peeking from the right side, as shown:

[image]

These are the settings used:

```
for (var i in data.image_set) {
    sc.append('<div><img src="' + data.image_set[i].image + '" height="' + data.image_set[i].height + '" width="' + data.image_set[i].width + '"></div>');
}
sc.slick({
    dots: true,
    speed: 150,
    centerMode: true
});
```

I would like to have the slider display only one image at the center, and optionally have the previous and next images partially visible to the left and right sides respectively. How can this be accomplished?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.sc').slick({
    dots: true,
    speed: 150,
    centerMode: true
  });
});
```

```css
.sc img {
  height: calc(50vh - 100px);
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.5.9/slick.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.5.9/slick-theme.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-alpha1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.5.9/slick.min.js"></script>
<div class="sc">
  <div>
    <img src="https://lespider-ca.s3.amazonaws.com:443/I152rUr6ZBih.png?Signature=YFF9BB8dlAe7okzBHnRLWgYmFI8%3D&amp;Expires=1452236979&amp;AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAIS4C7GGEGJPLLSMA" height="900" width="674">
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://lespider-ca.s3.amazonaws.com:443/HvAQty35hkNv.png?Signature=8HQKRBefUe%2B4f3sKX1vag78dCbQ%3D&amp;Expires=1452236979&amp;AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAIS4C7GGEGJPLLSMA" height="673" width="900">
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://lespider-ca.s3.amazonaws.com:443/A6CZ5y6EUmNg.png?Signature=bsArQ0sX8o9mtgIISwtFPW2hzSM%3D&amp;Expires=1452236979&amp;AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAIS4C7GGEGJPLLSMA" height="673" width="900">
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://lespider-ca.s3.amazonaws.com:443/EGO36t7pzBWp.png?Signature=txW6IP9KJ8bB0S%2B9QCYQTEy6Q%2BQ%3D&amp;Expires=1452236979&amp;AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAIS4C7GGEGJPLLSMA" height="673" width="900">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: link to live code or can you share working fiddle ?

Comment: There's a lot of other irrelevant stuff on the same page, I'll try to whip up a minimal version hold on

Comment: Done, updated OP, this code produces the same effect, only difference is full page instead of just inside a bootstrap col. There seems to be no difference with or w/o the img `height` and `width`

Comment: if you add `margin:0 auto` to your img tag in CSS, it aligns the images in the middle automatically.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.sc').slick({
    dots: true,
    speed: 150,
    centerMode: true
  });
});
```

```css
.sc img {
  height: calc(50vh - 100px);
  width: auto;
  margin: 0 auto; /* it centers any block level element */
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.5.9/slick.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.5.9/slick-theme.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-alpha1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.5.9/slick.min.js"></script>
<div class="sc">
  <div>
    <img src="https://lespider-ca.s3.amazonaws.com:443/I152rUr6ZBih.png?Signature=YFF9BB8dlAe7okzBHnRLWgYmFI8%3D&amp;Expires=1452236979&amp;AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAIS4C7GGEGJPLLSMA" height="900" width="674">
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://lespider-ca.s3.amazonaws.com:443/HvAQty35hkNv.png?Signature=8HQKRBefUe%2B4f3sKX1vag78dCbQ%3D&amp;Expires=1452236979&amp;AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAIS4C7GGEGJPLLSMA" height="673" width="900">
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://lespider-ca.s3.amazonaws.com:443/A6CZ5y6EUmNg.png?Signature=bsArQ0sX8o9mtgIISwtFPW2hzSM%3D&amp;Expires=1452236979&amp;AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAIS4C7GGEGJPLLSMA" height="673" width="900">
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://lespider-ca.s3.amazonaws.com:443/EGO36t7pzBWp.png?Signature=txW6IP9KJ8bB0S%2B9QCYQTEy6Q%2BQ%3D&amp;Expires=1452236979&amp;AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAIS4C7GGEGJPLLSMA" height="673" width="900">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It works! Thank you :) How did you know that, is there any way I could've found out on my own from docs etc.? I mean the slick.js docs doesn't have any css in there, but this seems like a fundamental feature that a lot of people would use...

Comment: its basics of CSS! i just tried it on browser, it worked

Comment: Ah I never actually sat down and learned CSS lol, learning as I go :) One last question, in `0 auto`, what does the `0` do? edit: sorry I just found it from another question lol, `Specifying auto as the second parameter basically tells the browser to automatically determine the left and right margins itself, which it does by setting them equally. It guarantees that the left and right margins will be set to the same size. The first parameter 0 indicates that the top and bottom margins will both be set to 0.`

Comment: @DavidTan even i learn't nothing, everything's on the go ! :) `margin:0 auto` - it is equal to **:** `margin:0 auto 0 auto;`, it can be read as: `margin: top right bottom left` and in shorthand: `margin: topbottom leftright;`

Comment: That makes a lot more sense than the other answer. But just one small detail, I just checked W3S and they say the order is top-right-bottom-left? http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_margin.asp edit: Oops I see what you mean in the last part now, got it! Thanks!

Comment: how to do this in vue?

Answer (score 11):

The issue is coming from the fact that each individual slide is a div that automatically spans the width of the carousel, but the images do not fill the divs completely and, by default, are left-aligning inside their containers. Try adding something like this to your styles:

```
.sc div { text-align: center; }
.sc img { margin: auto; }
```

Comment: Ah ok, So basically the `margin: auto` gives the image left and right margins evenly to center it inside that said div, is that correct?

Comment: here, `margin:auto` means, `margin: auto auto auto auto;` it applies `auto` value to all sides.

Answer (score 2):

Had similar issues, when all the imgs didn't have the same height, they didnt align up into the slider:
find `.slick-track` in your "slick.css" and change `display` to `flex` and add `align-items: center`.

[image]